# Is it possible to use a factory method to create instances of your class using fluent nhibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

For example, I have a set of domain classes. Those classes implement a common interface. The interface is public but the classes themselves are internal. Instances of those classes can be created by using a provided factory that is public. Furthermore, each class instance is persisted using a one-table-per-hierarchy technique.

How can Fluent NHibernate be used is this case? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Blake

Answer (score 2):

This is more NHibernate specific than FNH, but you have two options as far as I can see.

1. Implement `IInterceptor.Instantiate(string entityName, EntityMode entityMode, object id)` - you would also have to associate said interceptor with any NHibernate sessions you start.
2. As per http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2008/11/entities-behavior-injection.html , subclass `ReflectionOptimizer' and implement the`CreateInstance()` method (need one for each type you want to build a factory for). There is some configuration and wiring I don't fully understand, and I suspect this is basically an overkill version of method #1.

If you are wanting to inject persisted fields and properties for your domain class, I'm not sure if there is a way to do that as it is a rather non-trivial matter to generalise.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take advantage of the event system in NHibernate 2.0+. The `Load` event allows you to create the object for NHibernate, as well. All you have to do is create an implementation of `ILoadEventListener`, add it to the event listeners for the `ISessionFactory` or `ISession`, and profit!

```
 using NHibernate.Event.Default

 public class MyCreatorListener : DefaultLoadEventListener
 {
   // this is the single method defined by the LoadEventListener interface
   public override void OnLoad(LoadEvent theEvent, LoadType loadType)
   {
     if(null == theEvent.InstanceToLoad) // Not null if user supplied object
     {
       theEvent.InstanceToLoad = MyFactory.Create(loadType); // Or whatever.
     }
   }
 }
```